# Python virtual environment: python file imports from lib\site-packages only if it's stored in lib\site-packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-import

Here is my folder structure:

myProject

- analysis.ipynb
- myvenv
  --- Lib
  --- Scripts
  --- pyvenv.cfg

I created my virutal environment following this:

```
cd myProject
py -m virtualenv myvenv
myvenv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

This is what I got:

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\author\myProject>
```

I continued to install packages and had it in the "myvenv\Lib\site-packages".

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\author\myProject> py -m pip install requests
...
...
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.31.0
```

But when I ran "import requests" from my "analysis.ipynb" file, it said "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'". But then I placed the "analysis.ipynb" file in the folder "myvenv\Lib\site-packages", it successfully imported the package "requests".

I do not want to do this manually. Do you have any thoughts or experiences with this?

Comment: after activation of your environment try `python -m pip install requests`

Comment: How did you run your python code? You show the commands when you activated your virtual environment and installed a package. Then what did you do? And what command did you use to move the .ipynb file and what command did you run it with?

Comment: This is the normal behavior of virtual environments in Python. Unless you specify otherwise, the venv will ignore your global site-packages.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just cut/pasted the .ipynb file to the folder site-packages manually.

Comment: @hieunguyen Feel free to answer the rest of my questions when you have some time. Also, what is `py`? Is this an alias for `python`? Where is it defined.